# Adult film where a company develops a device that can show you dreams

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for an adult film of likely the softcore type that I watched around 8–10 years ago on a DVD player (it could be on a DVD or VCD disc). The concept was that a company had developed a device that could show you dreams as you wore it on your head. And in that dream, you can have sex with anyone you want.

Another thing I recalled is that people came to the person with the VR-type thing to experience virtual pleasure. And the VR had some problems, maybe because someone was using it and suddenly the virtual person turned into an alien or something. I can't recall exactly; it was just some flashes I could recall. It was a really old movie, maybe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. What do you mean by you watched it back in CD? Like disk format? Or is CD a place? If there's anything else you remember about the movie, please be sure to [edit] it in

Comment: yeah in disk format. played on my tv with the help of a DVD player.

Comment: Do you remember what the device looked like?

Comment: Do you remember any other bits of that plot? Was the sex the entire plot, like porn? Did someone die due to the headset? Is it almost the millennium?

Comment: FWIW, VCD was a different format than DVD, but often played in DVD players.

Comment: *Brainstorm* and *Strange Days* come to mind, but in both cases, the sex is recorded and replayed, and is a relatively isolated incident (albeit plot-important).

Comment: This sounds very much like an episode of a sitcom where the main characters go to visit a guest star who has developed a VR headset & game (the main characters are going to invest in the start up company) where the main point of the game is to have sex. I'd swear it's an episode of _The Big Bang Theory_, but a quick perusal of episodes failed to identify one. Maybe I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: @FreeMan Sounds like something that might have happened on Silicon Valley too.

Comment: Never heard of that one, @CristobolPolychronopolis, so it's definitely not the one _I'm_ thinking of... :)

Comment: I think it was on HBO or one of those channels.  The overall tone of the show lends itself more to porn goggles than Big Bang.

Comment: How *adult*? Softcore pornography (a la *Forbidden Science*) or actual hardcore pornography?

Comment: @Valorum Softcore type of...its really hard to recall anything else because it was way back and i had watched some part of it once..

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it might be VCD but we played it on a DVD player.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots so another thing i recalled is people came to the person with the VR type thing to experience virtual pleasure. And the VR had some problem may be because someone was using and suddenly the virtual person turned into an alien or something,,,i can't recall exactly...its just some flashes i could recall..it was a really old movie maybe

Answer (score 7):

I think this is *Emmanuelle in Space 5: A Time to Dream*.

The synopsis is “Emmanuelle teaches her alien friends to explore sexual fantasy through their dreams, and searches for her own dream lover”. And IIRC, a group of men and women got together in a circle wearing headsets, which let them connect to each other's brains. In this way, Emmanuelle could share with them her erotic dreams. Or something like that. It was silly.

Or maybe it's *Emmanuelle 3: The Meaning of Love*, from the same series, because I found an image of her wearing [said headset](https://img4.bdbphotos.com/images/500x250/z/z/zzdft1cr8n6ccdrz.jpg).

[image: image described above]

Answer (score 0):

Could this be *Demolition Man*?

Our hero and heroine decide to have sex using a shared headset device. Unused to the experience, John Spartan rips off the headset after having experienced flashes and images.